# Why do I need to make a new variable for this code to work?

Tags: javascript

I was doing a codewars challenge where I had to make a program that will turn a certain set of numbers to the square of those numbers. So for example, let's say the number given is 232. What I have to do is split those 3 numbers and give the square to each individual number. So the eventual answer for 232 in this case will be 494 as 2 square is 4 and 3 square is 9. I completed the challenge with this code

```js
function squareDigits(num){
  let numStr = String(num)
  let split = numStr.split("");
  let arr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i <= split.length-1; i++){
    let sqr = Math.pow(split[i],2);
    arr.push(sqr);
  }
  let join = Number(arr.join(""));
  return join
}

console.log(squareDigits(232))
```

The line of code after my for loop indicates that after the numbers were squared, it would be joined together to make it one number. My issue came when I **didn't** make a new variable and directly wrote `Number(arr.join(""))` and return the variable `arr`. The result was that the numbers did NOT become 1 whole number and it was still seperated.

The code before making a new variable:

```js
function squareDigits(num){
  let numStr = String(num)
  let split = numStr.split("");
  let arr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i <= split.length-1; i++){
    let sqr = Math.pow(split[i],2);
    arr.push(sqr);
  }
  Number(arr.join(""));
  return arr
}

console.log(squareDigits(232))
```

Why do I have to make a variable before the code will work

Comment: The problem with your first attempt simply is, that you are returning `arr` - but `Number(arr.join(""))` does not _change_ anything about `arr`. You don't have to create an additional variable, you can also just directly `return Number(arr.join(""));`.

Comment: Off Topic: you don't need the arrays `let result = ""; for(let digit of String(num)) result += digit**2; return +result;`

Answer (score 2):

[Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) does not modify the original variable, so it must process directly as an expression i.e.:

```
return Number(arr.join(""));
```

or stored in a variable:

```
let result = Number(arr.join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

`join` doesn't mutate the variable it operates on, but creates a new string.

```
Number(arr.join("")) // NOT doing anything to the arr variable here,
                     // the evaluated expression isn't assigned to anything

return arr // the unchanged value of arr is returned
```

But you can simply put the return statement on the line before:

```
return Number(arr.join(""));
```